# Use Regex in registry_data_exists Resource in Chef Recipe

Tags: windows, chef-infra, registrykey

I am creating a chef recipe and trying to create/update Registry key using registry_key resource. How I can use regex to validate the presence of the registry key and only update if it is necessary

`registry_key'HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\WindowsNT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon' do
    values [{
    name: 'SCRemoveOption',
    type: :string,
    data: '1', }]
    #  recursive true
    action :create
    not_if { registry_data_exists?('HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon',{ name: 'SCRemoveOption', type: :string, data: '1' } ,:x86_64) }
end`

If the registry key exists with data 1 or 2 or 3, There is no need to udpate or else the registry_key-data should be updated to 1.

```
not_if { registry_data_exists?('HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon',{ name: 'SCRemoveOption', type: :string, data: '([1-3])'} ,:x86_64) }
```

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies for previous effort)

I have preferred using a powershell_script resource as I know PS syntax better than ruby/Chef. I used to check with Security Policy was enabled/disabled as follows:-

```
  powershell_script 'my_script' do
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    cwd 'C:\Temp'
    code <<-EOH
      <...set the registry key(s)...>
    EOH
    not_if '(get-itemproperty HKLM:\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Lsa).DisableDomainCreds -eq "1"'
  end
```

Perhaps you can adapt to make it work with an array or values.

Comment: Craig, Thanks for your suggestion, I need to verify the data not whether the key exists or not.